# SQL Server query: Sum columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these 3 tables:

- `APPOINTMENT`: APPT_TIME, CUST_ID, STY_ID, SERVICE_ID, PROD_NUM
- `PRODUCT`: PROD_NUM, PROD_TYPE, PROD_NAME, PROD_VENDOR, PRICE
- `SERVICE_`: SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_DESC, EST_TIME, PRICE

What I need to do is sum the `PRICE` from `PRODUCT` table and the `PRICE` from the `SERVICE_` table for each appointment/customer.

Here is what the result needs to look like:

```
CUST_ID    final_price
------------
1234       45.16
4678       63.25
4587       78.58
7894       25.15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   A.CUST_ID 
       , SUM(ISNULL(P.PRICE,0) + ISNULL(S.PRICE,0)) Final_Price
FROM APPOINTMENT A 
INNER JOIN PRODUCT P   ON A.PROD_NUM = P.PROD_NUM
INNER JOIN SERVICE S   ON S.SERVICE_ID = A.SERVICE_ID
GROUP BY A.CUST_ID
```

Comment: Or left joins if prod_num or service_id can be null.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `prod_num` and `service_id` are unique keys (or primary keys) in their respective tables, then aggregation is not necessary.  To accomplish this you should use a `left outer join`, just in case some appointments don't have both fields:

```
select a.cust_id,
       (coalesce(p.price, 0) + coalesce(s.price, 0)) as Final_Price
from appointment a left outer join
     product p
     on p.prod_num = a.prod_num left outer join
     service s
     on s.service_id = a.service_id;
```

If there could be multiple rows in the reference tables for a given product or service, then you should do the aggregation before the join.